# gulp connect not opening browser

Tags: gulp, gulp-connect

I tried setting up the least possible setup for gulp-connect. It shows the following in the terminal window: `Server started http://localhost:8080`. However it doesn't start Chrome as expected and seen in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KURMrW-HsY4).

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect');

var outputDir = "wwwroot";

gulp.task('connect', function() {

 connect.server({
    root: [outputDir],
    open: {browser: 'Google Chrome'}
})});
```

Comment: They have removed that option as far as I can tell. If you read the youtube comments, you will see someone asking the same thing. Not sure if they ever got it to work. The plugin hides connect's events so this is a tough case. You can always write another task to open the browser and have the `connect` task as a dependency.

Answer (score 7):

I did some research and didn't found any options for `open` in gulp-connect. So I'm going to assume that he used an older version of the module witch supported that feature.

**Option 1:**

To solve your problem you can use [gulp-connect-multi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-multi), a forked version of gulp-connect witch includes browser opening functionality.

**Option 2:**

If you still want to use gulp-connect I recommend using a module called [gulp-open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-open) (or even just open) that opens files and urls in the browser.

**Option 3:**

Search for more or create you own.

Best of Luck.

Comment: gulp-connect-multi is deprecated

Comment: OPTION 2! is in 2019 a better one

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue with gulp-connect. Then I have fixed this issue by installing another package named [gulp-connect-multi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-multi)

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-connect-multi

var connect = require("gulp-connect-multi")();

gulp.task('html', function () {
    gulp.src(config.paths.html).pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist)).pipe(connect.reload());

});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

To connect to my browser sync, I navigate to my gulp folder in cmd (the one that has node-mudules, in your project folder) and just type in "**Gulp**". It automatically opens my project in the browser.
Hope this helps.